# How to get clipboard image from Qclipboard mimeData in c++?

Tags: c++, qt, clipboard

So here is the deal, I am trying to get clipboard image (any format), and the method I am trying either returns NULL or return text formatted path of image like this

[image]

I've googled it and I've asked on reddit as well, but I couldn't figure out what's going on.

So there are the methods I've tried

(1)

```
const QClipboard *cb = QApplication::clipboard();
const QMimeData *md = cb->mimeData();
QListWidgetItem *item = new QListWidgetItem();
QLabel *label = new QLabel();
if (md->hasImage())
{

    label->setPixmap(cb->pixmap());
    ui.listWidget->setIconSize(QSize(100, 200));
    ui.listWidget->addItem(item);
    ui.listWidget->setItemWidget(item, label);

}
else if (md->hasText())
{
    ui.listWidget->addItem(cb->text());

}
```

(2)

```
label->setPixmap(cb->image());
```

(3)

```
HBITMAP MemoryManager::ImageFomClipboard(HWND hWnd)
{
    if (!OpenClipboard(hWnd))
        return NULL;

    HBITMAP hBitmap = (HBITMAP)GetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP);
    CloseClipboard();
    return hBitmap;
}

std::string MemoryManager::get_image(std::string number)
{
    HWND hWnd = GetDesktopWindow();
    HBITMAP hBitmap = ImageFomClipboard(hWnd);
    if (hBitmap != NULL)
    {
        CImage image;
        image.Attach(hBitmap);
        image.Save(_T("C:/temp/asx.bmp"), Gdiplus::ImageFormatBMP);
    }
    return "C:/temp/asx.bmp";
}
```

(1) st method was returning the path of image

(2) nd method returned null

(3) rd method returned only print screen images. Don't know why, could be because of .bmp format.

I am completely clueless now how do get this issue sorted, please help me out.

Comment: to the [1], try this: QImage img(cb->image());
        label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));

Comment: @Xplatforms, awesome dude, it worked but just for print screen not for an normal image. Any idea why ?

Comment: This is correct, If you copy image data, you have Image in clipboard, but if you copy image file, you have the path to that file in clipboard. Just load this path to QImage and set it the same way.
**else if(md->formats().contains(QStringLiteral("text/uri-list")))
    {
        QImage img(QUrl(cb->text()).toLocalFile());
        label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));**

Comment: @Xplatforms Awesome dude.. It worked like a charm. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All thanks to @Xplatforms i got this solution,

```
QImage img(cb->image()); label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
else if(md->formats().contains(QStringLiteral("text/uri-list"))) { QImage img(QUrl(cb->text()).toLocalFile());
     label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
```

Thanks again @Xplatforms :) you rock.